# Alljoyn openSSL issue for android N

Tags: android, alljoyn

My application is crashed when I install it on the Android N. Please see the log below:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: alljoyn dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf" referenced by "/data/app/com.example.myapp-1/lib/arm/liballjoyn_java.so"...

Following announcement from Google, Android is moving away from OpenSSL to the BoringSSL library. So if we still use the openSSL, our application will be crashed. Have someone known how to fix this issue? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue [1] has been fixed in the latest Alljoyn builds, so please use version 15.04/15.09a or 16.04.

Conversely, if you are forced to use an older version, this link might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283150/2442831

[1]https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE-1248

Comment: Just found out that I Forgot to update liballjoyn_java.so. Problem solved. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: If the answer helped to figure out the issue, please consider to accept it